# How to solve the error in Crystal report Formula Editor

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

```
    totext(count({Emp.Name},{Sal.Name}),"#,###")+" "+if count ({Emp.Name},
{Sal.Name})<>1 then {Sal.Name} + " Accounts" else

    {Sal.Name}+" Account"
```

There must be a group that matches this field. Error in Formula Group count.

Above report query - **Emp.Name and Sal.Name fields datatypes are varchar**. Values are loaded correctly in print preview. But **error throw on runtime**.

Please help this issue. Thanks for Advance..!

Comment: create a group using `{Sal.Name}` and then compile the code

Comment: Hi Siva, how to create group with {Sal.Name}. Can you please explain briefly? Thanks.

Comment: **count({Emp.Name},{Sal.Name})** i try to check this condition, i have issues faced on this condition.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code `count({Emp.Name},{Sal.Name})` means you are trying to count the employee name with respect to the sal.name group, hence this error.

Go to `Insert --> group --> In window select sal.name` which will create a group for you.

once group is created then check the formula